# How can I plot this kind of smoothed probability distribution in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, distribution, probability

[image]

Comment: do you know the equation to your pdf?

Comment: As presented in that image, that isn't a probability distribution - it's not even a function. Perhaps the axes should be swapped?

Comment: @Matt: It IS a probability distribution. Conventionally the axes are swapped, however that doesn't mean this is not a probability distribution. You can have axes as you want.

Comment: @yoda: This is just for demonstration process. Let's say if the distribution is lognormal. What do you mean by `equation to your pdf`?

Comment: your pdf (probability density function) should have an equation that describes it. You probably know it, but didn't understand what I meant by pdf. See my answer below for an explanation of how to plot it for log-normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the equation to the PDF, you can simply plot it for specified values of x. For example,

**Normal distribution**

```
pNormal=@(x)1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-(x.^2)/2);
x=linspace(-4,4,1e3);
plot(x,pNormal(x));
```

**Log-Normal distribution**

```
pLogNormal=@(mu,sigma,x)1./(x*sigma*sqrt(2*pi)).*exp(-((log(x)-mu)./(sqrt(2)*sigma)).^2);
x=linspace(0,10,1e3);
mu=0;sigma=1;
plot(x,pLogNormal(mu,sigma,x));
```

You can vary `sigma`, `mu` and `x` according to your needs. The log-normal distribution is defined for `x>0`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that uses a kernel smoother.  (Just in case you don't know what distribution describes your data sample)

```
% generate some random data
X1 = 10 + randn(100,1);
X2 = 15 + 2*randn(75,1);
X3 = 25 + 3*randn(125,1);
X = vertcat(X1,X2,X3);

% use a kernel smoother to model X
foo = fitdist(X,'kernel')

% inspect the methods of foo
methods(foo)

% Plot the pdf of foo
range = linspace(min(X), max(X), 100);
bar = pdf(foo, range)
plot(range, bar)
```